# Java generics extend

Tags: java

let's say I have :
`public class Animal{..}`

and `public class Cat extends Animal {...}`

```
public MakeNoise(Class<? extends Animal> animal1,
                 Class<? extends Animal> animal2){..}
```

why does `MakeNoise(new Animal(),new Animal())` doesn't compile?

while `MakeNoise(new Cat(),new Cat())` does compile.

is there any way to solve it without adding interface to animal and do:

```
Class<? extends AnimalInterface>
```

Comment: Because you want to pass in classes and not instances. So your method would have to be called like `MakeNoise(Animal.class, Animal.class)` and is probably not what you want. It should rather be `makeNoise( Animal animal1, Animal animal2) { ...}` (also note the lowercase `m` - read about the Java coding conventions). Besides that, there's probably an overloaded method that accepts `Cat` and thus allows for `MakeNoise(new Cat(),new Cat())`.

Comment: I know- I have a big application and want to avoid from big refactoring here. any idea how to do it that way ?

Comment: Your method signature seems wrong (you probably want to pass in instances rather than class definitions) and thus you'd need some refactoring anyways.

Comment: The second one does not compile either.

Comment: `MakeNoise(new Cat(),new Cat())` does not use the constructor provided in the question. `new MakeNoise(Animal.class,
                      Animal.class)` would compile however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why does `MakeNoise(new Animal(),new Animal())` doesn't compile?

Because `new Animal()` creates an instance of `Animal` not an instance of `Class`. Indeed `Class<? extends Animal>` refers to an instance of `Class` that is a sub type of the class `Animal` while you are dealing with instances of `Animal`.

What you try to achieve is rather this:

```
public MakeNoise(Animal animal1, Animal animal2){..}
```

Or assuming that `MakeNoise` is a class, you could define generics on your class definition as next:

```
public class MakeNoise<X extends Animal, Y extends Animal> {
    public MakeNoise(X animal1, Y animal2){..}   
}
```

Then you will be able to call

```
MakeNoise makeNoise1 = new MakeNoise(new Cat(), new Cat());
MakeNoise makeNoise2 = new MakeNoise(new Animal(), new Animal());
```

If `MakeNoise` is supposed to be a method (if so there is a typo in your question as there is no returned type), you can also define generic types in your method definition as you can see in the following example:

```
<X extends Animal, Y extends Animal> void MakeNoise(X animal1, Y animal2) {...}
```

---

> while `MakeNoise(new Cat(),new Cat())` does compile.

This **cannot** compile either for the same reason described previously

Comment: indeed makeNoise is a method. should I declare X, Y also in the class ?

Comment: No need if you only want generic types in your method. If you need to define generic types on your class, don't redefine them on the method otherwise it won't be seen by the compiler as the same generic types couple even if you use X and Y in both places